# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Sports breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  1          9
Users destroyed                                  23          0
Users contacted                                   3          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue            26        816
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue                0        122
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         11        605
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                0        229
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                 0        787
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue                5      1,198
Tag synonyms proposed                             0          6
Tag synonyms created                              0          5
Questions unprotected                             0          3
Questions reopened                               10          3
Questions protected                              22         42
Questions migrated                                9          0
Questions merged                                  5          0
Questions flagged⁴                                1        273
Questions closed                                168        205
Question flags handled⁴                         115        159
Posts unlocked                                    0          2
Posts undeleted                                   0         10
Posts locked                                      4         27
Posts deleted⁵                                  191        483
Posts bumped                                      0        354
Comments undeleted                                1          0
Comments flagged                                  0        501
Comments deleted⁶                               689        323
Comment flags handled                           391        110
Answers flagged                                   1        698
Answer flags handled                            452        247
All comments on a post moved to chat              1          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Sports](https://sports.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://sports.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://sports.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...